# compile scss with nodemon and node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, node-sass

I'm playing around with node.js, express and node-sass and watching for file changes with nodemon.

I added this bit to the app.js to compile the scss (according to the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-sass) docs) but it's not doing anything. I would like for the sass to compile when nodemon runs app.js every time I make changes to the project.

I'm not sure if it will even work with nodemon like this but just running node app.js in the console without nodemon does nothing so it must be something I'm doing wrong.

APP.JS FILE

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var sass = require('node-sass')

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(sass.middleware({
src: __dirname + '/public/scss',
dest: __dirname + '/public/css',
debug: true,
outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: The sass.middleware is there to respond to requests. Thus your sass is only compiled when a request for a particular css file is received. To do what you want to do you would be better off using the other functionality of node-sass and compiling it directly at restart (which is what nodemon does for you). eg., https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage